# Get client URL (proxy server)

Tags: python, http, url, proxy

I need your help to solve a problem in my proxy server.
So I try to get the url from the client but I don't get any url and I don't know why this is happens. I will be happy if you can help me fix it.

Code -

```
import os,sys,thread,socket

def proxy(conn, client_addr):

    # get the request from browser
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    # parse the first line
    url = request.split('\n')[0]
    print url # Nothing happened

def main():

    serv_soc = socket.socket()
    serv_soc.bind(("0.0.0.0", 5900))

    serv_soc.listen(10)
    conn, client_addr = serv_soc.accept()
    proxy(conn, client_addr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Does `request` contain anything before you call `split('\n')`? What sort of request are you sending to your code to test it?  Your code seems to work just fine when I test it (whereby "fine" I mean "it sees the request from a web client").

Comment: My code work as proxy server and he need to get url from the browser, my code need to print the site url but he not print anything. Maybe because i'm use mac ?

Comment: Your code is fine and also works for me. You should probably print the actual request to see what it contains.